# Passenger And Apache 'Something Went Wrong' Error , Works in WEBRick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, mod-rails

I am running Apache2 with Passenger and Rails. I am able to run my web app with 'rails s -e production' but Passenger will not run the app. It just gives the 500 error. The log is giving me the whole precompile error, but changing the config to precompile or 'rake assets:precompile:all' do nothing. I am working with an existing SQL database and it sometimes also gives a table not found error when running behind Apache, but works just fine in WEBRick. I have a "RailsEnv production" directive which did nothing either. I do not understand why it would not work with Passenger but with WEBRick, especially when I got it working with Apache before, then simply redeployed the app in a different directory and got these issues. There is also a cache: get miss error but I resolved it I believe, but my app still does not work. I have been working on it all day yesterday and today and still can not get the app to run with Apache. Already tried permissions, already tried reinstall, already tried db:migrate, already tried everything. Does anyone know why it is failing?